# no internet connection - how to update SLES servers?

Tags: repository, sles

We have a few SLES 11.4 servers that doesn't have internet connection nor connection to the repositories.

But these machines need updates too.

Usually we just use `zypper` to update, that fetches what is needed, installs them.

Local repo isn't a solution too..

**Q:** how do we know what package needs to be updated? where can we get those packages (automatically)?

We can copy to/from the servers with `sftp`, and have root, at least that is available :)

Comment: Servers not having by policy a *direct* internet connection, does not have to mean not having access to repositories.